# How to get this desired result using Index Function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not sure what is wrong with my formulae. My aim is to find 3 values in the given table.

[image: This image will give you guys a better clarity of question.]

My Expected results are {3,6,2} but the result I am getting is 6 only.

PFA image for better clarity.

[image: Results of formulae]

Comment: Try putting `=INDEX(A$2:A$7,B2)` in `C2` and populate down

Comment: (Without some fancy formula writing, or concatenating a bunch back-to-back, AFAIK returning three values in a single cell with `Index/Match` isn't possible).  Are you trying to return `3, 6, 2` in the same cell?

Comment: I can do that but is there any way by which I can get output in array format like {3,6,2} ?

Comment: @BruceWayne Not in the same cell but output is single number. I want my output to be an array - {3,6,2}

Comment: You can create a string if you have Office 365 Excel, but it would not be a true array but a string containing the correct output.  If you do not have Office 365 or want a true array then no it is not possible.  If you want to use the array in another formula then there are ways to do that skipping the output to a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return an array of the values to be used in another formula then use:

```
INDEX(A2:A7,N(IF({1},B2:B4)))
```

This turns any formula that uses it into an array formula that must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

For example

```
=SUM(INDEX(A2:A7,N(IF({1},B2:B4))))
```

Entered as an array will return 11

or if you have Office 365 Excel

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A2:A7,N(IF({1},B2:B4))))
```

Entered as an array will return `3,6,2` into a cell.

---

Now if you want to list the outcome in an array of cells.  Highlight three cells in a column and enter:

```
=INDEX(A2:A7,N(IF({1},B2:B4)))
```

And hit Ctrl-Shift-enter.  Excel will fill the three with the same formula and the results will be the array in order:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. Now I can use this array in another formula.